# Doctrine Paging

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-1.2

I have used pagination of doctrine.I have implement it successfully,But my problem is when the user click on the last page.In the pager after last page anchor tag,there are two empty anchor tag and if user click on first page,there are two anchor tag.I want when user click on last page,there should be no anchor tag after last page anchor tag and if user click on first,there should be no anchor tag before first page anchor tag.

example: this is my paging structure

```
                     << , < , 1 , 2 , 3 , > , >>

    anchor tag no:   1    2   3   4   5   6   7
```

If user click on the 1 no anchor tag,then there should be no first, previous anchor tags(anchor tag no. 1, 2).

And If user click on the 3 no anchor tag,then there should be no last,next anchor tags(anchor tag no. 6, 7).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should manually check whether the user landed on the last/first page and then update you anchor tags accordingly (i.e. disable them).